# Searching for POP3 emails with specific criteria (e.g., unseen mails, specific dates) using Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a project where I need to retrieve emails from a POP3 mail server based on specific search criteria, such as unseen mails or emails from a desired date onwards. I have researched several libraries for Node js, but most of them seem to focus on retrieving emails and then filtering them. I want to directly search for emails based on the desired conditions.

Are there any Node js libraries or methods available that allow me to search for emails on a POP3 server based on specific criteria, without having to retrieve and filter all the emails?

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this efficiently. Thank you!